# Error with a Salesforce Lightning Component in the Utility Bar (IE11)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have added a Lightning Component to the utility bar. I've tried viewing the component in a few different browsers on Windows 7 including Chrome and IE 11. When I check out the page in IE11, I get the following error:

```
Error in $A.getCallback() [Syntax error]
b()@https://abc.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/5JCxDHzie8H3zsdbyGSxGw/aura_prod_compat.js:8:41
a.createForDef()@https://abc.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/5JCxDHzie8H3zsdbyGSxGw/aura_prod_compat.js:8:235
Anonymous function():3:76
l():2:215
h.createPanel():3:15
```

I get this error when I click on the button for the Lightning Component down in the utility bar. The component is never displayed.

When I launch the IE11 Dev Tool (F12), I see an error in the console that reads:
**Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to set property 'id' of undefined or null reference**

Also, just above this error in the console are two lines that repeat the text:
**Your browser doesn't support notification API**

At this point, I don't know what could be the cause of the error, nor do I know how to further troubleshoot this issue.

Any ideas of what could be causing this issue (or how to further troubleshoot this)?

Comment: The problem itself being ie11? Should check supported browsers for lightning

Comment: Is this a component you wrote, or a component you installed?

Comment: If you wrote it, could you **[edit]** this post to include the code?

Answer (score 2):

> Your browser doesn't support notification API

Its not clear if this is actually part of the component you are using, if it is, it is normal that it does not work in IE 11, as stated in the error message, the current browser does not support it. You can double check under

[Notification API Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Browser_compatibility) section.

might also be worth while that you check:

[Supported Browsers for Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5)

If you dont have access to the code base, it will be pretty hard to troubleshoot, although this should be achievable if you set some breakpoints in the source code's file (usually referenced in the console along the error message) and spend a while understanding why this happens.

The error you referenced:

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to set property 'id' of undefined or null reference

should be accompanied by a line # with the file name where this is happening.